# Luatex ligatures after \newpage

Tags: luatex, ligatures

I am seeing some *very strange* behavior with LuaLaTeX. It is hard to describe, so I will begin with a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={Common, TeX}}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
%\setmainfont{Adobe Caslon Pro} % also fails

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textit{fianc\'ee} \\ % correct
{\itshape fianc\'ee}  % correct

\newpage

\noindent
\textit{fianc\'ee} \\ % wrong
{\itshape fianc\'ee}  % wrong

\newpage

\noindent
\textit{fianc\'ee} \\ % wrong
{\itshape fianc\'ee}  % wrong

\end{document}
```

This is the rendering of page 1:

[image: Page one]

And page 2:

[image: Page two]

In the above, the fi ligature is correctly used on the first page, while on the 2nd and 3rd pages I get the two characters. I have tested it for both Garamond and Caslon. I do not get this error with xelatex.

BTW to complicate things this does not happen in the upright case :)

This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2014041116 (rev 4627)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Strange indeed. Let's see if others are able to reproduce it; I don't have those Pro fonts, sorry.

Comment: I have Adobe’s Garamond Premiere Pro and cannot reproduce the problem.  Which version of `luatex` do you use?

Comment: I have been trying to think of a convenient font to test it on that has that ligature in the itshape.

Comment: This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2014041116 (rev 4627)

Comment: OK, I used a remote system that has LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012091206 (TeX Live 2012/Debian), and it works correctly with the **exact same** OTFs... is this worth a bugreport?

Comment: It works here with LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013070317 (rev 4627), the latest update available for 2013.

Comment: That is odd indeed... I am using the same rev, just a different build date.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Very strange, and sounds as if a bug report is needed, but I never know whether the report should go to `luatex`, to `luaotfload`, to `fontspec`, or...

Comment: A (negative) data point: I am *unable* to replicate the problem you report when I run your MWE on my system (MacOSX 10.9.2), using either the beta test version of TeXLive2014 (LuaTeX version: 0.79.1) or MacTeX2013 (LuaTeX version: 0.76.0),

Comment: Works for me too (0.76 from Mac Tex Live 2013). It could also be a problem with `luaotfload` – my version is `2013/12/28 v2.4`. And just a wild guess: is there any difference if you load the font with `Renderer=Basic` (default being `Full`)?

Comment: I get the same result with Renderer=Basic. I think it may be something with the build. Anyway, the question should probably be closed.

Comment: @sujeet Please post the output of ``luaotfload-tool --version``.

Comment: @phg luaotfload-tool version 2.2, database version 2.204.

Comment: @sujeet Too old. The current version is 2.4, please update.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which cannot be reproduced and is likely down to a specific version of the font loader.